# Callback before deletion of file

Tags: python, windows, filesystemwatcher

Is there a callback when windows delete message box shows when deleting a file? I've tried using File System Watcher, but the callback is triggered after the file was deleted.

Comment: You need to employ the filesystem filter driver which intercepts requests *before* they are processed. Our CallbackFilter product does the job, but it doesn't have python API.

Comment: This might be possible using an Explorer plug-in, but I'm not very familiar with the technology.